# Mongoose query with undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose to construct a query equivalent to this SQL:

```
select * from problems where tutorialNumber is not null
```

I've tried:

```
    var q = Problem.find().where('tutorialNumber').ne(undefined);
    q.exec(callback);
```

It returned an error: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "undefined" at path "tutorialNumber"

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Please post your schema for the `Problem` model. That is likely where the root problem lies.

Comment: Have you tried `.ne(null)` rather than `.ne(undefined)`?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the replies. I found another way to do it:

```
var q = Problem.find().exists('tutorialNumber', true);
q.exec(callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several syntax options. I believe your code is OK other than you should use `null` instead of `undefined`. I prefer the style that is a little closer to normal mongo shell:

```
Problem.find({tutorialNumber: {$ne: null}}, callback);
```

or you can do

```
Problem.find().ne('tutorialNumber', null).exec(callback);
```

But I believe the way you are using `where` and `ne` are also correct.

However, the `CastError` can mean there's a problem in your schema (could be trying to nest models instead of nesting schema).